# layout creation like instagram in css

Tags: html, css

I tried to create a layout like instagram in css but faced an issue. i want it to be 3 grid like instagram with a gap of 10px  on desktop mode and on below 768px i want it be single grid. i.e @media(max-width:768px) it should be 100% width.work link is attached of codepen[Codepen link of work][1]
[1]: https://codepen.io/TA0011/pen/eYjGvyV

```js
const targets = document.querySelectorAll('[data-target]');
const contents = document.querySelectorAll('[data-content]');

targets.forEach(target => {
  target.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    const t = document.querySelector(target.dataset.target)
    
    targets.forEach(t => {
      t.classList.remove('active')
    })
    contents.forEach(c => {
      c.classList.remove('active')
    })
    
    t.classList.add('active');
    target.classList.add('active');
  })
})
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
}
body{
  padding: 5%;
}
.menu{
  display:flex;
}
.menu p{
  margin-right: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
.content{
  margin-top:2rem;
}
[data-content]{
  display:none;
}
.active[data-content]{
  display:block;
}
.menu .active{
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#FFF;
  background: #000;
  padding:  5px 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.cards{
  display:flex;
  flex:1;
  flex-basis: 33.33%;
  max-width: 33.33%;
  min-width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.card{
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <p data-target="#initial" class="active">Initial</p>
  <p data-target="#product">Product</p>
  <p data-target="#contact">Contact</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div data-content id="initial"  class="active">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="card">
      abc
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      abc
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      abc
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-content id="product">
    <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      lmn
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      lmn
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      lmn
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-content id="contact">
    <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      xyz
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      xyz
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      xyz
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave class names left, mid, right to 3 separate fields. After max-width:768px, I hidden the left and right areas, I created the spaces by giving margin. My English is not very good, you can contact me if you don't understand :)

```js
const targets = document.querySelectorAll('[data-target]');
const contents = document.querySelectorAll('[data-content]');

targets.forEach(target => {
  target.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    const t = document.querySelector(target.dataset.target)
    
    targets.forEach(t => {
      t.classList.remove('active')
    })
    contents.forEach(c => {
      c.classList.remove('active')
    })
    
    t.classList.add('active');
    target.classList.add('active');
  })
})
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
}
body{
  padding: 5%;
}
.menu{
  display:flex;
}
.menu p{
  margin-right: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
.content{
  margin-top:2rem;
}
[data-content]{
  display:none;
}
.active[data-content]{
  display:block;
}
.menu .active{
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#FFF;
  background: #000;
  padding:  5px 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.cards{
  display:flex;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.card{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #fff;
    flex-grow:1;
    margin-left:10px;
    padding: 15px;
    max-width:33%;
    width:33%;

}
 .card.left, .card.right{
    display:none;
 }
 @media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
   .card{
      max-width:100%;
      width:100%;
      margin-bottom:10px;
   }
    .card.left, .card.right{
    display:none;
    }
    .contact .cards, .product .cards { 
      flex-direction: column;
    }
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width:320px) {
   .menu p{
      margin-right: 1rem;
      font-size:12px;
   }
  }
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <p data-target="#initial" class="active">Initial</p>
  <p data-target="#product">Product</p>
  <p data-target="#contact">Contact</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div data-content id="initial"  class="active">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="card left">
      abc
    </div>
    <div class="card mid">
      abc
    </div>
    <div class="card right">
      abc
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-content id="product" class="product">
    <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      lmn
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      lmn
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      lmn
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div data-content id="contact" class="contact">
    <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      xyz
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      xyz
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      xyz
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Serdar Göleli i'll check and let you know by tomorrow. please come online tomorrow.

Comment: @Sean yes you are right, thank you for your warning, i will make the necessary edit.

Comment: below 768 px it should display one box. Earlierit was alright

Comment: And problem is if there is one box it occupies 100%width.

Comment: @mits 
It will be one box, right? 3 boxes in a row will not appear. And the width of the box will be 100%. this is how i updated it. You would check again

Comment: let me be very clear, 3 boxes when in desktop views and one box in mobile view. for desktop view when 3 boxes are not there it should occupy 1/3rd of the row. For mobile view it should be 100%.

Comment: Can you check. @mits

Comment: 3boxes in product and contact should be width 100% below  768px stacked one above the other with a gap of10px.i mean flex-direction: column. others is alright.

Comment: please do it. you're almost there.

Comment: @mits Can you check

Comment: Almost done but it looses its responsivity below 320px. Try to fix this till 250px

Comment: @mits Can you check

Comment: BRO i guess you didn't get me.... code before this was correct but it is notb responsive till 250px